# Receiving Notifications for Individual Task Completion OmniThreadLibrary Parallel.ForEach

Tags: multithreading, delphi, omnithreadlibrary

I'm employing Delphi 10.4 along with OmniThreadLibrary, utilizing the Parallel.ForEach construct to execute tasks. However, I'm encountering an issue where I'm only notified when all tasks have been completed. Is there a method to receive notifications when individual tasks finish, similar to the schedule mechanism or async foreach? Below is a snippet of my code for reference:

```
`procedure TfrmForEachOutput.MSGNewData(var msg: TOmniMessage);
begin
  OutputDebugString('Finish');
end;

procedure TfrmForEachOutput.ProcessTransactions(input: TList<TSSRINTBWTH>; output: TList<TTransaction>);
var
  outQueue   : IOmniBlockingCollection;
  transaction: TOmniValue;
begin
  outQueue := TOmniBlockingCollection.Create;
  Parallel.ForEach(0, input.Count - 1)
    .TaskConfig(Parallel.TaskConfig.OnMessage(Self))
    .NoWait
    .Into(outQueue)
    .Execute(
    procedure(const task: IOmniTask;const value: integer; var result: TOmniValue)
    begin
     result := TTransaction.Create(input[value],task);
    end
  );
  for transaction in outQueue do
  begin
   output.Add(transaction.AsObject as TTransaction);
  end;
end;
    ....
    ....
begin
  task.Comm.Send(MSG_NEWDATA, '');//this executed only when all tasks has been completed
end;`
```

[image]

Thank you

I tried schedule with no sucess.